# Are there any TC39 proposals to assign a property from one object to another?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I often write things like:

```
  objA.propA = objB.propA;
  objA.propB = objB.propB;
  // or
  const { propA, propB } = objB;
  objA = { ...objA, propA, propB };
```

propA and propB feel redundent here. Is there a simpler syntax like:

```
  const { propA, propB } = objB;
  objA[{ propA, propB }];
```

or maybe
`objA['propA', 'propB'] = objB`

Comment: Doesn't `objA=objB` work?  If the objects are Arrays, you might want to `objA=objB.slice()`, but a more general way I'd use is `objA=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objB))` - I think it will copy properties only, and you'd lose methods.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no, there's not a built-in syntax shortcut for this other than the object destructuring you already showed in the question. I guess you could make a helper function `assignProps(objA, objB, "propA", "propB")` but it has the disadvantage of having to put the prop names in strings.

Comment: Would [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) be sufficient?  Something like `Object.assign(objA, { propA, propB })`?  Or are you specifically interested in removing the intermediate step of pulling `propA` and `propB` off of `objB` before assigning to `objA`?

Comment: Actually Object.assign is as succinct as my first example, so that's great to know and unlike using object destrucuring, it doesn't needlessly create a new object. I wonder if immer supports Object.assign, if so, more bonus points!

It'd be nice to have a solution as succinct as the second example, but I can't even imagine a language syntax that would make that possible.